# SQL Server Query solution cum Suggestion Required

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a following scenario in my SQL Server 2005 database.

`zipcodes` table has following fields and value (just a sample):

```
zipcode     latitude   longitude
-------     --------   ---------
65201      123.456     456.789
65203      126.546     444.444
```

and `place` table has following fields and value :

```
id     name     zip      latitude   longitude
--     ----     ---      --------   ---------
1      abc      65201     NULL        NULL
2      def      65202     NULL        NULL
3      ghi      65203     NULL        NULL
4      jkl      65204     NULL        NULL
```

Now, my requirement is like I want to compare my zip codes of `place` table and update the available latitude and longitude fields from `zipcode` table.

And there are some of the `zipcodes` which has no entry in `zipcode` table, so that should remain null.

And the major issue is like I have more then 50,00,000 records in my db. So, query should support this feature.

I have tried some of the solutions but unfortunately not getting proper output.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like

```
UPDATE place
SET     latitude = z.latitude,
        longitude = z.longitude
FROM    place p INNER JOIN
        zipcodes z ON p.zip = z.zipcode
```

See example

```
DECLARE @zipcodes TABLE(
        zipcode VARCHAR(10),
        latitude   FLOAT,
        longitude FLOAT
)

DECLARe @place TABLE(
        id INT,
        name VARCHAR(10),
        zip VARCHAR(10),
        latitude FLOAT,
        longitude FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @zipcodes SELECT '65201',123.456,456.789 
INSERT INTO @zipcodes SELECT '65203',126.546,444.444

INSERT INTO @place SELECT 1,'abc','65201',NULL,NULL 
INSERT INTO @place SELECT 2,'def','65202',NULL,NULL 
INSERT INTO @place SELECT 3,'ghi','65203',NULL,NULL 
INSERT INTO @place SELECT 4,'jkl','65204',NULL,NULL 

UPDATE @place
SET     latitude = z.latitude,
        longitude = z.longitude
FROM    @place p INNER JOIN
        @zipcodes z ON p.zip = z.zipcode

SELECT  *
FROM @place
```

You can verify this from documentation

[UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)